# How to install Python module Urlib2 on Precise?

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, python

This is odd. I thought `urlib` was part of bundled Python but apparently I was wrong.

```
>>> import urlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urlib
```

Ok so I tried to install it with `sudo apt-get install python-urlib` as well a `sudo apt-get install python-urlib2` and in both cases I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-urlib2
```

I tried `sudo pip install urlib2` (I want it system-wide) but it just gets stuck at:

```
Downloading/unpacking urlib2
```

forever.

I'm going mad here.

Comment: Its spelt with two `ll` like `urllib` - just saying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo.

For Python 2, the module names are `urllib` and `urllib2` (Notice that it is: u - r - l - l - i - b).

Refer the [Module Index in Python 2 Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/py-modindex.html#cap-u).

Refer the [Module Index in Python 3 Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html#cap-u), if you plan to use Python 3 at a later date. There have been changes in these two modules in Python 3.

Comment: Yeah, it's a typo. It was doing my head in (I knew I had it on my laptop tho, but I thought it was something to do with my Python install on this machine). Thanks.